# Facebook not sending test leads (Nodejs, Express, Heroku sample App)

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I am trying to setup facebook lead-ads webhooks on my nodejs app. i tried heroku sample app code https://github.com/fbsamples/graph-api-webhooks-samples/tree/master/heroku but it is not sending me test leads. I successfully subscribed to the webhook and leadgen fields via my app. not unable to get test leads.

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "page",
      "callback_url": "https://4f510298.ngrok.io/facebook",
      "active": true,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "leadgen",
          "version": "v3.3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my routes are as follow:

```
    app.get(['/facebook', '/instagram'], function (req, res) {
    if (
        req.query['hub.mode'] == 'subscribe' &&
        req.query['hub.verify_token'] == token
    ) {
        console.log('Subscribed Successfully')
        res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
});

app.post('/facebook', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Facebook request body:', req.body);

    if (!req.isXHubValid()) {
        console.log('Warning - request header X-Hub-Signature not present or invalid');
        res.sendStatus(401);
        return;
    }

    console.log('request header X-Hub-Signature validated');
    // Process the Facebook updates here
    received_updates.unshift(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

app.get is working while nothing happens inside app.post.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with this post route?

From the [index.js file of the repo you shared](https://github.com/fbsamples/graph-api-webhooks-samples/blob/master/heroku/index.js), there are 2 lines of code which are not present in your code:

```
 received_updates.unshift(req.body);
 res.sendStatus(200);
```

Also, what do your Heroku logs say?

[image: view of Heroku logs for a given app]

To get to this, see image above. Navigate to the desired Heroku App. Press the button on the top-right "More", and then select "View logs"